# M2CryptoWin64 Python3.5 Windows10 Pycharm installation and __m2crypto import error

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, pycharm, importerror, m2crypto

I'm trying to install M2Crypto for Windows 10. Using Python3.5. I think I've installed it all correctly, have swig and openssl `ImportError: No module named '__m2crypto'`.

```
File "C:\Users\Name\projects\project_name\authentication.py", line 13, in <module>
    from M2Crypto import EVP, RSA
File "C:\Users\Name\projects\project_name\venv\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import __m2crypto
ImportError: No module named '__m2crypto'
```

In the library though I can see there is a __m2crypto.py file. I've looked at just about every Stackoverflow and Github question on this issue and similar issues and have tried each of the solutions but I'm not having any luck in resolving it. Any help would be much appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You will be probably better to download built artifacts from [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/m2crypto/m2crypto/history).